# How does Two Phase Commit really work at low level?

Tags: sql, .net, algorithm, design-patterns, microservices

There are tons of articles on 2 phase commit on the internet.
They are all saying the same thing and I am not getting it. I need a low-level understanding of it.

The orders and Payment service example is the most popular example on the internet.

Let's say we have Orders service and Payments service. When an order is placed, the Order service writes it to its database but the payment service must also write it to its own database in order for the transaction to be complete.

**Here is my inadequate understanding:**

1. User sends a place order request to Orchestrator
2. Orchestrator invokes Orders service to as well as Payment service at the same time. Now according to what I have read, Order and Payment services are supposed to respond to Orchestrator by telling it whether or not they are ready. *What does that mean? What does it mean to be ready here?*
3. Order and Payment service respond back, telling Orchestrator that they are "ready" (*whatever that means*).
4. Orchestrator sends another request to both the services (commit request).
5. Order writes the record to its database. The Payment service writes the record to its own database. They both respond back with status 200 to Orchestrator.
6. Orchestrator checks if both of the participants have returned status code 200. If yes, then it does nothing. If no then it asks them to ABORT?? *How? One of the participants already wrote the transaction to its database.*

Comment: Your understanding is flawed; there is no first step where nothing happens only for the second step to be irreversible. The first step consists of participants tentatively executing the request and reporting back "I did it", the second step is the coordinator sending the "finalize" or "roll it back" command based on whether everyone did it. And yes, transactions must be capable of being aborted (rolled back) at any time before the final "commit" signal is given; this can be implemented in various ways. WP has a [decent article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Comment: Note that databases (at least relational ones, but also most other types) already implement transactions themselves. For a service it then becomes trivial to implement: all it has to do is start a DB transaction, perform the request, report back, and then rollback or commit it as instructed. How the rollback is implemented need not concern it; that's the problem of the database. (Typically, the database stores a copy of the original data with the transaction in the log, so the rollback consists of writing this copy back.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert first step "User sends a place order request to Orchestrator" is user clicking a button on UI. I am aware that's not part of 2pc.  
What do you mean when you say that first step consists of participants tentatively executing the request and reporting back "I did it". How is that first step? wouldn't first step be orchestrator sending request to participants?

Comment: Yes, but the request is also immediately executed (with an option to roll back). I'm not sure what you're looking for beyond the Wikipedia article, which I think explains it quite well. Basically, the orchestrator asks everyone to do what they're supposed to do and report back success or failure, then when all nodes have reported back, it asks all nodes to go ahead with commit or rollback based on the collective results (commit if all nodes report success, or rollback if at least one reports failure).

Comment: @JeroenMostert The wikipedia or any other article that I found on the internet is very abstract. Of course, patterns by definition are abstract. But I needed details like for eg : if for an inventory management project you have 5 microservices. Does it mean all of them could be co-ordinator services at some point if needs be? Or does it have to be a different service (6th service) whose role will be to co-ordinate all transactions in the Inventory Project? And what if the orchestrator itself fails?

Comment: The coordinator role could be taken up by an individual service, or it could be central; that's not crucial to the mechanism (though if you're going for a microservice architecture, it would seem to make the most sense to make it its own service, or cluster of services). If the orchestrator fails, the system as a whole fails -- so it had better be built to be resilient and redundant. Of course 2PC is not the only way to coordinate things; the example orders and payments system is one where I would not expect it (payment and order status, successful or not, can be processed separately later).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two-phase commit is all about handling failures and what they mean.

In phase 1, the orchestrator tells the order and payment services to prepare to commit.  If everything goes well, they both respond with "prepared", which means:

- The transaction is recorded durably, and marked prepared
- There is no possibility that it will need to be rolled back due to conflicts or for any other reason, except the failure of some other service to prepare.  Once the transaction is prepared, only the orchestrator can normally roll it back.

If both the order and payment processors successfully prepare, then the orchestrator will tell them finalize the commit.  Finalized means:

- The transaction is recorded durably and marked committed
- It *cannot* be rolled back.

If anything goes wrong during this process, it's possible to check the durably recorded states of the transaction in both the payment and order services in order to determine whether it "really happened" and how to recover:

- If not all of the services prepare successfully, then the transaction did not happen.  The orchestrator will roll back the transaction in all the services that did prepare it.  If things are broken, this may require manual intervention, or the orchestrator may not be able to complete this operation until things come back up.
- If all of the services did prepare successfully, then the transaction did happen.    The orchestrator will tell all the services that haven't finalized it to go ahead and do that.  Again, this might have to wait until systems that are down come back up.

Also, sometimes it's not the orchestrator's job to recover.  If the orchestrator gives up, then the individual services can check with each other to see if the transaction happened or not.

The important point is that once the two-phase commit starts, no matter what happens you can return the system to a consistent state by checking the durable transaction records.

In practice, two-phase commit is not used that often, because when transactions are in the prepared-but-not-finalized state, any other transactions that use their data cannot themselves commit, because they might need to be rolled back.  This kind of contentions where transactions need to wait for each other slows the whole system down.

Comment: That's a good answer. Thank you. I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain the steps of a successful purchase to you. The customer registers an order and then goes to the payment gateway and makes the payment there and returns to the store site and the payment record is recorded and the operator can track the steps.

**Order table**

```
Id int,
CustomerName nvarchar(150),
TotalPrice int,
SendState tinyint,
InsertDate datetime
```

**Payment table**

```
Id int,
OrderID int,
PayState tiniyint,
PayPrice int
```

*The customer now **registers** an **order** in the database*

```
Insert into Order values(1,'bill',30000,1,'5/1/2021 8:30:52 AM')
```

*Now the customer connects to the payment gateway and makes the payment successfully and the store site returns.*

```
Insert into Payment values(1,1,200,30000)
```

The results are now displayed for the operator

```
select o.*,p.PayState,p.PayPrice 
from Order o join Payment p on o.Id = p.OrderId
```

If you do not pay, an error of 500 will be registered in the database and the operator, seeing the status of 500, will understand that the payment was not successful.

```
Insert into Payment values(1,1,500,0)
```

Comment: This fails to explain anything about how a two-phase commit works. What happens if making the payment fails? Note that the question presupposes separate services, which may not be using the same database, or indeed any database at all.

Comment: Suppose that if you do not pay, an error of 500 will be registered in the database and the operator, seeing the status of 500, will understand that the payment was not successful.

Comment: Who is "the operator"? A human being? A piece of software? What happens to the order if the payment fails? A two-phase commit means all steps succeed, or all operations are reverted, so the state as a whole is consistent. What you are describing here is only the happy flow, which doesn't deal with any failure at all.

Comment: The salesperson reviews the orders and considers only the orders registered with the 200 message to be successful. The rollback transaction is not ideally stored in the database so that the customer may complete the payment operation later

Comment: What you're describing is in principle a fine way to build an order system (in practice you indeed would not want to roll back anything), but unfortunately it has nothing to do with the original question, which presupposes a system that uses two-phase commits for the transactions, which your implementation does not. The example is only an example -- the OP isn't looking for advice on how to build a system like this but for an explanation on how two-phase commits work.

Comment: I do the same in my real projects. The said question is recorded in two tables at the same time. This can also be updated only on the return of payment instead of insert status :)

Comment: The tables are spread across multiple databases. Had it been a single database why would anyone want to use 2phase commit when we have transactions. Now even in most NoSql databases.

Comment: If the tables are in multiple databases, use the join below (select *
from Db1.dbo.table1 a
join Db2.dbo.table2 b on a.Id = b.Id)